# how to use rewrite, if first rewrite doesn't yield a result (search in different locations)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I use the following rewrite rule to retrieve files from a different directory and it works nicely:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^((ffmpeg|ffprobe|ffserver|ffplay)-[0-9]+-g[0-9a-z]+\.(?:7z|dmg))$  /pub/$2/snapshots/$1  [L]
```

However, only 30 files are kept in `/pub/$2/snapshots/$1` and older files are moved to a different "archive" directory (e.g. `/pub/archive/$1`).

Is there a way to rewrite to `/pub/archive/$1`, if the file isn't available in `/pub/$2/snapshots/$1` anymore?

Comment: Yes there is, and you are using it already ... `!-f`

Comment: @CBroe I've tried several different methods, also adding another -f rewritecond, but it didn't work.

Comment: _Show us_ what you tried (and explain your reasoning), otherwise it didn’t happen.

Comment: I asked a question, which means I don't know the answer. I expected that someone who knows the answer could help me. However, `!-f` does not help.

Comment: I'm sorry, is this a place to ask questions or a place to get mocked with a hehe-I-know-the answer-but-I'm-not-gonna-tell-you attitude? How useful is it for others, if I write 25 examples that didn't work? I ask a question like what is 534*734 and somebody answers: hey, try numbers in the range of 250,000 to 500,000. You still won't know which one it is, but I know that one of them is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What no one has pointed out to you is that, [as per the docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond), `RewriteCond`s accept backreferences to the matched pattern in the `RewriteRule`. So where you are currently testing that the request is *not* a regular file you would instead check your preferred substitution *is* a file. Repeat this for your fallback substitution.

---

**Edit:** the `RewriteCond`s in your comment don't make sense, the first part should be the subject of the test, the second part the test. You put the backreferences to the rule in the subject. Obviously, you've had a go, try this:

```
RewriteCond /pub/$1/snapshots/$0 -f
RewriteRule ^(ffmpeg|ffprobe|ffserver|ffplay)-[0-9]+-g[0-9a-z]+\.(?:7z|dmg)$  /pub/$1/snapshots/$0  [END]
RewriteCond /pub/archive/$0 -f
RewriteRule ^(?:ffmpeg|ffprobe|ffserver|ffplay)-[0-9]+-g[0-9a-z]+\.(?:7z|dmg)$  /pub/archive/$0  [END]
```

Comment: Yep, I tried that too. Didn't work:

`RewriteCond ^((ffmpeg|ffprobe|ffserver|ffplay)-[0-9]+-g[0-9a-z]+\.(?:7z|dmg))$`
`RewriteCond "/pub/$2/snapshots/$1" -f`
`RewriteRule ^((ffmpeg|ffprobe|ffserver|ffplay)-[0-9]+-g[0-9a-z]+\.(?:7z|dmg))$  /pub/$2/snapshots/$1`

`RewriteCond ^((ffmpeg|ffprobe|ffserver|ffplay)-[0-9]+-g[0-9a-z]+\.(?:7z|dmg))$`
`RewriteCond "/pub/archive/$1" -f`
`RewriteRule ^((ffmpeg|ffprobe|ffserver|ffplay)-[0-9]+-g[0-9a-z]+\.(?:7z|dmg))$  /pub/archive/$1`

Comment: I really would not have asked, if I knew the answer. I tried almost anything. I'm guessing I'm missing a path (absolute instead of relative), used a wrong flag, or whatever. If someone has encountered this and used such a construct on their server, why not paste a few lines of code here? It seems that people don't want to give a straight answer, because they don't want to make it easy for the person who asked. What's up with that?

Comment: Thank you @Walf I do appreciate your answer though.

Comment: Unfortunately I got a `500 Internal server error`. It seems that Apache doesn't like the END flag. `RewriteRule: unknown flag 'END'` was in the Apache log. I replaced it with `[L]`, but now none of the files were served. (Only got a 404.) Maybe the RewriteCond thinks it is an absolute file system path instead of a URL. I'll play around with it a bit.

Comment: Ok, the`RewriteCond` only takes an absolute file system path. With that it worked. Success! I've also figured out what my problem was all the time. The documentation states: _RewriteCond backreferences: These are backreferences from the last matched RewriteCond in the current set of conditions._ I apparently misread that sentence. A backreference is usually a reference to a previously defined grouping, but in this case it takes a reference from a rule that comes **after** the current condition. Your example helped me to understand my error. Thank you.

Comment: Old Apache, consider using 2.4. Sorry, I figured your example already used absolute paths because of the leading `/`. You should be able to use `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pub/$1/snapshots/$0 -f`

Comment: You're half right, lexical order != execution order. Rule patterns are matched before checking the conditions, and the conditions can receive rule backreferences (`$0` - `$9`) and subsequent conditions as well as the rule's substitution can receive both rule (`$0` - `$9`) and condition backreferences (`%0` - `%9`).

Comment: I'm using Apache 2.4 on my server, but the MAMP installation on my MacBook uses Apache 2.2. I tried `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` and also `%{SERVER_NAME}` but both didn't work. Anyway, as long as it works somehow, I'm happy.

Comment: If you have to use `L`, use `DPI` too.