# Redirect requests for moved files to subdirectory

Tags: mod-rewrite

I want to move a bunch of files from DocumentRoot on an Apache2 VirtualHost to a subdirectory /archive/ and establish a mod_rewrite rule so that if Apache doesn't find a file in the DocumentRoot it will look for it in /archive/.  This is what I have now:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName myserver.com
    ServerAlias www.myserver.com
    ServerAdmin admin@myserver.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/myserver.com/public_html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    RewriteEngine On

    # Disable HTTP methods other than GET and POST

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(GET|POST)
    RewriteRule .* - [R=405]

    # Redirect to moved files

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /archive/$1

    # Force HTTPS

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =myserver.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.myserver.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

</VirtualHost>
```

The rules to disable HTTP request methods and to force https work fine, but the redirect for moved files isn't, and I can't figure out why.

This question differs from [how to use rewrite, if first rewrite doesn't yield a result (search in different locations)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50325200) because the issue there was how to write conditions to check multiple directories for a file while my issue was single-folder redirect rules that were not working due to 1) placement in the incorrect virtual host and 2) %{REQUEST_FILENAME} not returning the full path to the file. None of the answers at 50325200 solves or addresses the problem I was having.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use rewrite, if first rewrite doesn't yield a result (search in different locations)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50325200/how-to-use-rewrite-if-first-rewrite-doesnt-yield-a-result-search-in-different)

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of troubleshooting, I discovered that I had two issues: since I was also rewriting to direct all http traffic to https, my rewrite was being undone.  I moved these rewrite rules to the VirtualHost for *:443 and that solved part of the problem.

The other problem was that inside the VirtualHost %{REQUEST_FILENAME} was not returning the full path to the file, but only raw URI.  I had to modify my Rewrite conditions as follows:

```
RewriteCond /var/www/myserver.com/public_html%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond /var/www/myserver.com/public_html%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /archive/$1.
```